# Proving equality between first element of sequences, one encapsulated in another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following assumption, which is that a sequence is a finite sequence of other members:

$\langle x_{1}, ..., x_{m} \rangle \space = \space \langle y_{1}, ..., y_{m}, ..., y_{m+k}\rangle$
for $ 1 \leq m \leq k \leq n \implies x_{1} = \space \langle y_{1},...,y_{k+1} \rangle$

*Known*:
$\langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle = \langle y_1, ..., y_m \rangle \implies x_i = y_i $ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n $.  The claim is that for this equality to hold, $m$ and $n$ can be unequal only if some $x_i$ is itself a finite sequence of $\langle y_1, y_2, ..., y_j \rangle$ or the other way around.

A finite sequence of members of $A$ is defined as $S = \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle$, where $x_i \in A$.  A segment of the finite sequence $S$ is defined as a finite sequence $\langle x_k, x_{k+1}, ..., x_{m-1}, x_m \rangle$.  $ 1 \leq k \leq m \leq n$. Iff k = 1, then this is an initial segment.  The n-tuple is defined recursively by $\langle x_1, ..., x_{n+1} \rangle = \langle \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle, x_{n+1} \rangle$.

This is out of Enderton's *Introduction to Logic* book, however am having difficulty finishing the inductive proof.

**Proof by Induction** on $m$

Base case $P(1) = \space \langle x_1 \rangle = \langle y_1 \rangle$.

Show $P(m) \implies P(m+1)$ and assume $P(m)$ (inductive hypothesis).

$P(m+1)\space=\space\langle x_1, ..., x_m, x_{m+1}\rangle\space=\space\langle y_1, ..., y_m, ..., y_{m+k}, y_{m+1+k}\rangle$

The first components of the ordered pair must be equal (see definition of n-tuple): $\langle x_1, ..., x_m \rangle = \langle y_1, ..., y_{m+k} \rangle$. Apply inductive hypothesis P(m).  $\dashv$

$\langle \langle y_1, ..., y_m, ..., y_{m+k}\rangle, x_{m+1}\rangle \space=\space \langle \langle y_1, ..., y_m, ...,y_{m+k}\rangle, y_{m+k+1}\rangle$

Now we need to show that, $x_{1} = \langle y_{1},...,y_{k+1} \rangle$ holds here.

Update: I suspect the following is why this holds, Let $m = 1$ then:

$\langle \langle y_1, ..., y_{k+1}\rangle, x_{2}\rangle \space=\space \langle \langle y_1, ..., y_{k+1}\rangle, y_{k+2}\rangle \therefore x_1 = y_1 = \langle y_1, ..., y_{k+1} \rangle$

If we let $m=1$ and $k=1$ then:

$\langle \langle y_1, y_2\rangle, x_{2}\rangle \space=\space \langle \langle y_1, y_2\rangle, y_{3}\rangle$

If the sequences both includes another finite sequence inside and let $m=1$, $k=1$ and $z=1$:

$\langle \langle y_1, y_2, y_3\rangle, x_3\rangle \space=\space \langle \langle y_1, y_2, y_3\rangle, y_4\rangle$

As you can see there is pattern between both sides of the equality based on values of $m$, $k$ and optionally $z$.

Thanks!

Comment: In general, the base case will fail. For example if $x_1=42$ and $y_1=666$

Comment: A couple more items mentioned before the proof.  $<x_1, ..., x_n> = <y_1,..., y_m> $ then $x_i = y_i$ for 1 <= i <= n.  The claim is that $m$ and $n$ can be unequal only if some $x_i$ is itself a finite sequence of $<y_0, y_1, ..., y_j>$ or the other way around.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: There is more than one way to set-theoretically define a finite sequence. Which  definition does Enderton give? You must $use$ a definition.

Comment: Thanks, I added the definition near the top of the post.